# Lambda expressions in Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, lambda, ognl

I'm still using Struts 2.3.16. I have round tripped the Struts2 documentation and tried to use lambda expression on my JSP page. But it doesn't work. Also in my previous answers I have used a parenthesized expressions to evaluate nested expressions in OGNL. But it seems doesn't work anymore.

This is lambda expression that doesn't work

```
<s:property value="#fib =:[#this==0 ? 0 : #this==1 ? 1 : #fib(#this-2)+#fib(#this-1)], #fib(11)" />
```

This is parenthesized expression from the answer that doesn't work

```
<% String str27 = "hello27"; %>
<%ActionContext.getContext().getValueStack().set("str27", str27); //set to root %>
<s:property value="str27"/> <br>
<%ActionContext.getContext().getValueStack().getContext().put("str27", str27); //set to context %>
<s:property value="#str27"/> <br>
<s:set var="str28" value="'str27'"/>

str28: <s:property value="%{(#str28)(0)}"/><br>
```

I also know that it works if I use `value="%{#attr[#str28]}"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The evaluation of OGNL expressions is disabled by default since `2.3.14.1` because of security vulnerability  (see [S2-013](http://struts.apache.org/docs/s2-013.html) for more details).

Of course you can enable evaluation by setting `struts.ognl.enableOGNLEvalExpression` to `true`.

```xml
<constant name="struts.ognl.enableOGNLEvalExpression" value="true" />
```

But it is **not recommended**.

Instead use:

```xml
<s:property value="#attr[some_var]"/>
```

Comment: Ok, now tell me why this working with `top`,`#root`,`#attr`,`#request`,`#context`, and not working with for example `#str27`?

Comment: @RomanC: Because `top[some_var]` is not expression evaluation.

Comment: Could you elaborate it, I thought everything inside %{} is an OGNL expression and [] is an index. So, how this index evaluated at `top` because it doesn't have properties like `some_var`?

Comment: @RomanC: Disabled is just an eval part. But of course you can access properties.

Comment: I'm not looking at the source code at the moment, could you elaborate how indexes are evaluated. For example `session.attribute["foo"]` evaluated because `session` has a method `getAttribute(String name)`.

Comment: @RomanC: *The "indexing" notation is actually just property reference*. So `array["length"]` is the same as `array.length`.

Comment: But not in the case `top.some_var` because top doesn't have a property `some_var`. But `top[some_var]` is evaluated, why? It also doesn't have a property with the name returned after `some_var` evaluation.

Comment: @RomanC: This is because expression in `[]` will be evaluated first. Consider this example: `String foo = "length";` the `array.foo` expression throws exception because there is not `foo` property in the array, but in `array[foo]` the `foo` will be evaluated to a string `length` so `array["length"]` will return length of the array.

Comment: Ok, evaluated expression in `[]`, so the result should be `top.str27` but `top` is an action and it doesn't have this property.

Comment: @RomanC: The `top` is not an action in your example, and because of that it works. But hence it is not general solution I will remove it from the answer.

Comment: Ok, last three objects `#attr`, `#request`,`#context` also evaluated correctly, why? Neither of them has a key nor property `str27`.

Comment: @RomanC: Of course it there, you've put this value to the context. :)

Comment: So, why it's not working `#action[#str28]`? Also `#context` is not a value stack context, and it's note a joke. It's just could be a bug or something else. When I first knew about it I was a bit confused.

Comment: @RomanC: The `context` is OGNL context. The value **must** be in OGNL context. IMO not a bug. What exactly do you think is a bug? That value is available in `#attr` or `#context`? It should be there if you put it there.

Comment: But the value is not in the `#context` it's in the value stack context, so why it's searchable here? I haven't put it there as you see from the question.

Comment: @RomanC: If you've put variable to value stack of course it will be in OGNL execution context. How can you access any variable if not so? This is a basics of OGNL and S2.

Comment: This is not convincing. I would like more elegant explanation. As I said `#action` _in OGNL execution context_, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @RomanC: Chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54552/discussion-between-aleksandr-m-and-roman-c

Comment: Are you kidding? I've already upvoted it. I will accept it if you convince me with the complete answer. Till now the question is answered partially. The same request to you, remove downvotes from my questions and answers if you have.

Comment: @RomanC: Which part is unanswered? You asked why evaluation don't work and this answer explained it.

Comment: I said `value="%{#attr[#str28]}"` is worked, and I'd like you to explain why this worked, why `#context` and `#request` id worked, why `#action`, `#session`,`#application` won't work. You can use any facts reference docs, code examples, it should be convincing.

Comment: @RomanC: Like I told you before you have put it into the value stack therefore you can access it in `#attr`, `#context` and `#request`. Try `value="#context.str27"` and you'll see it is there. The `#action` is irrelevant here like I explained to you in the chat. As for the `#session` and `#application` those are way different scopes. You can put this value into the session and you will get it with `#session`. Which part you don't understand?

Comment: @AleksandrM The parts with words.

Comment: @DaveNewton Excuse me, what parts with words?

Comment: @AleksandrM I didn't put it into request,session, application scope, I didn't put it into OGNL context, but why this works differently?

Comment: @RomanC: Because those are different things. Scope != context. IMO we are way out of scope of this OP. Maybe you can think this through and ask another question with exactly part which you don't understand.

Comment: Ok, Thank you for your effort. If no buddy wish to answer it, then committing.

Comment: Yes I prefer have questions highly upvoted, or remove alltogether.

Comment: I want to remove this question, do you know how to do this?

Comment: @RomanC: Remove? Why? It is a good question. It can help other peoples too.

Comment: It helps only you, not me. Or you think I needed help to answer this question? Ok, upvoted back because of the link.